# Can the GPIO pins be used for serial communications?

Tags: pi-3, gpio

I in the planning/information gather stage.

I want to replace the guts of a robo dog with a raspberry pi 3.  It seems to have 8 serial interfaces with 8 pins(not necessary all in use).

I am trying to figure out the minimal amount of additional circuitry necessary to communicate with each of the 8 parts.

My first though was to divvy the 20 GPIO pins.  What is the fastest speed I could achieve?  How bad would this be for CPU utilization?

Comment: `It seems to have 8 serial interfaces` ...that does not make complete sense ..... which robo dog is it?

Comment: @jsotola  The Sony Aibo (210 I think).  Each leg,arm, head, and etc have individual control ports.

Comment: I'm pretty sure these aren't RS232 control ports, but I²C or SPI.

Comment: he said serial, not RS232...... I2C and SPI are both serial as well.

Answer (score 1):

Rpi has only one serial UART channel. So for 8 channels, you need to use software to config GPIO pins as UART.  However, software UART on rpi/linux is not that reliable, even at low speed (9600baud).

Or you can use 8 SC16IS750 modules for hobbyists (less than US$10 from eBay).

[image: SC16IC750 I2C UART module]

SC16IS750 is a slave I2C-bus/SPI interface to a single-channel UART.

- offers data rates up to 5 Mbit/s and low operating and sleeping current.
- enables protocol conversion from I2C-bus or SPI to and RS-232 and are fully bidirectional.

[SC16IS750 Datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/SC16IS740_750_760.pdf?)

.END

Comment: Does one chip give me 8 ports or 1?  Do I need to make room for 8 of these chips?

Comment: Only one UART channel on one board.  So you need 8 boards for 8 UART channels.  Each board is about 2.5cm x 3cm.