# using GPIO pins as TX/RX pins

Tags: gpio, serial, uart

I'm working on a project that needs multiple TX/RX pins, but the Raspberry Pi that I have only has 1 of these pins. Can I use the GPIO pins as TX/RX pins? Or is there an adapter available somewhere?

Specifically, I need the TX/RX pins for a SIM module and a GPS module. Perhaps there are SIM and GPS modules that uses GPIO directly instead? Any links would be helpful

Comment: Related if not dupe: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/98393/19949 , https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/96697/19949 , https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/83918/19949 , and (if a Pi4): https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/99954/19949

Comment: @Ghanima None of the Dupe's mention Software Serial and from my understanding that is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @MatsK fair enough, but I still consider it related and these might very well be applicable. The OP seems to be open minded about the solution (e.g. they consider peripherals that do not use a serial interface at all).

Comment: @Ghanima I agree that it is kind of related.

Comment: @aldo, Ah, let me see, you can consider two things: (1) Switch to Rpi4B, which has FIVE hardware uarts: TxD0 to TxD4, RxD0 to RxD4, (2) Use USB to serial adapters/cables.  Say, if you have a 9 port USB hub, and 9 USB/TTL cables, you can talk to 9 SIM/GPS modules at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way that is called "Software serial" or "Soft UART".

The project **https://github.com/adrianomarto/soft_uart** is doing precisely what you are looking for, you can install the `soft_uart` and use any GPIO as Rx/Tx.

> **Software-based serial port module for Raspberry Pi.**
>
> This module creates a software-based serial port using a configurable
>   pair of GPIO pins. The serial port will appear as `/dev/ttySOFT0`.
>
> **Features**
>
> - Works exactly as a hardware-based serial port.
> - Works with any application, e.g. cat, echo, minicom.
> - Configurable baud rate.
> - TX buffer of 256 bytes.
> - RX buffer managed by the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You could a USB to serial converter.  That would let you connect the USB end to the Pi and the serial TX/RX/Ground end to the serial device.

You can use (my) [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) to bit bang a serial link on any spare GPIO.

As long as the baud rate is 19k2 or less it should be fine.

For Python the [read](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#bb_serial_read_open) is straightforward.  [Writing](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#wave_add_serial) requires waves and needs more effort.